# как проверить контент System.in на то, является ли он zip архивом, или просто текст?

Tags: java

Есть такой код -
`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); String text = reader.readLine();`

Мне надо проверить содержимое на то, является ли контент zip архивом?

Comment: А что если контент zip и там подпорчено в конце?

Comment: Если zip то буду разархивировать, а если нет то наоборот. Пробовал либу стороннюю Tika - но что-то не получается

Comment: Читать дескриптор заголовка файла и сопоставлять с известными.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону ZipInputStream

Comment: Считать несколько первых байт и сравнить: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934178/how-to-identify-a-zip-file-in-java

Comment: Несколько байт потом все хорошо?

Comment: первые байты в zip какие то особенные?

Answer (score 0):

Решил так - создал массив байтов из двух присущих Zip, и сравнил первые два байта из полученной строки:

```
        `InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        byte[] pattern = fromHexString("50 4B");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String text = reader.readLine();
        byte[] buffer = text.getBytes();
        if (buffer[0] == pattern[0] && buffer[1] == pattern[1]) {
        ... }`
```

Вот метод, который возвращает массив байтов из записанных с строку значений байтов:

```
   `public static byte[] fromHexString(String src) {
    byte[] biBytes = new BigInteger("10" + src.replaceAll("\\s", ""), 
    16).toByteArray();
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(biBytes, 1, biBytes.length);
    }`
```